# Pandas — match last identical row and compute difference

Tags: python, pandas

With a DataFrame like the following:

```
         timestamp    value
0       2012-01-01      3.0
1       2012-01-05      3.0
2       2012-01-06      6.0
3       2012-01-09      3.0
4       2012-01-31      1.0
5       2012-02-09      3.0
6       2012-02-11      1.0
7       2012-02-13      3.0
8       2012-02-15      2.0
9       2012-02-18      5.0
```

What would be an elegant and efficient way to add a `time_since_last_identical` column, so that the previous example would result in:

```
         timestamp    value   time_since_last_identical
0       2012-01-01      3.0                         NaT
1       2012-01-05      3.0                      5 days
2       2012-01-06      6.0                         NaT
3       2012-01-09      3.0                      4 days
4       2012-01-31      1.0                         NaT
5       2012-02-09      3.0                     31 days
6       2012-02-11      1.0                     10 days
7       2012-02-13      3.0                      4 days
8       2012-02-15      2.0                         NaT
9       2012-02-18      5.0                         NaT
```

The important part of the problem is not necessarily the usage of time delays. Any solution that matches one particular row with the previous row of identical value, and computes something out of those two rows (here, a difference) will be valid.

*Note: not interested in `apply` or loop-based approaches.*

Comment: Are you sure about the sample output? Why 2012-01-05 is 5 days from 2012-01-01 but 2012-01-09 is 4 days from 2012-01-05?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple, clean and elegant `groupby` will do the trick:

```
df['time_since_last_identical'] = df.groupby('value').diff()
```

Gives:

```
   timestamp  value  time_since_last_identical
0 2012-01-01    3.0                        NaT
1 2012-01-05    3.0                     4 days
2 2012-01-06    6.0                        NaT
3 2012-01-09    3.0                     4 days  
4 2012-01-31    1.0                        NaT
5 2012-02-09    3.0                    31 days
6 2012-02-11    1.0                    11 days
7 2012-02-13    3.0                     4 days
8 2012-02-15    2.0                        NaT
9 2012-02-18    5.0                        NaT
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
out = df.groupby(df['value'])\
        .apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['timestamp'], format = "%Y-%m-%d").diff())\
        .reset_index(level = 0, drop = False)\
        .reindex(df.index)\
        .rename(columns = {'timestamp' : 'time_since_last_identical'})

out = pd.concat([df['timestamp'], out], axis = 1)
```

That gives the following output:

```
    timestamp  value  time_since_last_identical
0  2012-01-01    3.0        NaT
1  2012-01-05    3.0     4 days
2  2012-01-06    6.0        NaT
3  2012-01-09    3.0     4 days
4  2012-01-31    1.0        NaT
5  2012-02-09    3.0    31 days
6  2012-02-11    1.0    11 days
7  2012-02-13    3.0     4 days
8  2012-02-15    2.0        NaT
9  2012-02-18    5.0        NaT
```

It does not exactly match your desired output, but I guess it is a matter of conventions (e.g. whether to include current day or not). Happy to refine if you provide more details.